# How to manage repetition in decorated ApiControllers?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, decorator, dry

I'm currently working on a project where every api controller needs to log activity. A rough example might be:

```
[Route(...)]
public IHttpActionResult Foo(...)
{
    using(var logger = ...)
    {
        // use the logger
        return _service.Bar(...);
    }
}
```

In my view, this has at least three issues.

1. Coupling the logging cross-cutting concern with the request handling violating the Single Responsibility Principle.
2. Coupling the `logger` implementation to the controller with `new` violating Dependency Inversion Principle.
3. Repetition of the `using` in each endpoint in each controller violating DRY.

I think I can fix (1) by decorating the controller, (2) with basic DI, and (3), I believe, will work itself out as a result. However, I incur another repetition issue by decorating controllers which have endpoints with `Route` attributes. Decorating the controller shouldn't make me dependent on a specific implementation to handle the routes so I need them in each decoration (more are likely) or find a way to inherit or reuse them.

```
// I can fluently handle logging with a LoggingController
// but I still need the route attribute
[Route(...)]
public IHttpActionResult Foo(...)
{
    return LogActivity(...).Foo(...);
}

private IController LogActivity(...)
{
    // do logging
    return _controller;
}
```

So far, I think I have two viable solutions:

1. Raise the level abstraction to an abstract class where I can inherit the attributes.
2. Provide a proxy decoration which simply delegates to whatever might be the outermost actual decoration.

(1) couples me to some base implementation and (2) couples me to a proxy/wrapper for each controller type. (2) seems like the better approach but it's questionable enough to wonder if there's some DI or AOP patterns that are meant to handle this.

```
// (2) with a decorator with no additional
// behavior or functionality delegates to 
// the given implementation.
[Route(...)]
public IHttpActionResult Foo(...)
{
    return _controller.Foo(...);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider action filters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: @felix-b, thanks, but from my first glance, I'm not thrilled with that. Mainly because it makes me choose to implement logging at the controller attribute level. That means that I'll too have to couple logging to each, or a specific, decoration. My hope is I will be able to add, change, or remove logging, or any other cross-cutting concern, without changing current implementations.

Comment: Oh I see. Then you can plug logging functionality into request pipeline, transparently to the rest of the code. Does it sound like a route you'd take?

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTTP message handler for ASP.NET (a middleware for ASP.NET Core), which you can plug into request pipeline, transparently to the rest of the code. In this way you achieve the orthogonality of cross-cutting concerns handling, and avoid repeating yourself.

Example of HTTP message handler with ASP.NET 4.5+:

```
public class RequestLoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // --> log begin of request
        // for example, you can include time measurement
        Stopwatch requestTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            // --> log successful completion
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // --> log failure
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you plug it in:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestLoggingHandler());

        //... the rest of the setup...
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core, there is also a new approach named `Middleware`. More details on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x#writing-middleware

Comment: Thanks, this is something I'll like to look into but will take me a moment to report on (+1).